# cURL conversation to jQuery or Ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

I am writing code from client that send a request to a server, the cURL command is below to make such an request:

The cURL script is:

```
curl http://test.com:8000/blah/blah/blah/TYPE/LA1/LO1 -d '{"target":[LA1,LO1]}' | json_pp
```

my js variables are sourced from a field:

```
var TYPE;
var LA1;
var LO1;
var LA2;
var LO2;
```

and the JSON pretty print at the end "json_pp"

I first wrote a laid js variable and handcrafted the curl in a url that was held in a variable, but that didn't seem to be wise nor efficient.

I created a node.js type function (which is probably wrong), how would this function be achieved in jQuery so that it is very clean and simple?

I know this request will return a JSON, how does a query store the response, where is it stored, can other functions access its values?

```
var request = require('request');
var TYPE;
var LA1;
var LO1;

var dataString = TYPE+"/"+ LA1 + "/" + LO1 + "/" + "-d"'{"target":[' LA2 ',' LO2 ']}'+ " | json_pp";

var options = {
    url: 'http://test.com:8000/blah/blah/blah/',
    method: 'POST',
    body: dataString
};

function callback(TAKES AND STORES IT INTO AN ARRAY OF OBJECTS) {

    }
}
```

Comment: What is dataString? I am not sure I understand what it is used for.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, what you want to do is to perform the above cURL request using jQuery. It would look like this:

```
function callbackFunction(result)
{
   console.log('Your data:', result);
}

$.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: 'http://test.com:8000/blah/blah/blah/',
  data: { 
           "origin": [LA1, LO2],
           "target": [LA2, LO2],
           "mode": TYPE 
        },
  success: callbackFunction,
  dataType: 'json'
}).fail(function( jqXHR, textStatus ) {
    alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
});
```

Comment: thanks for the response! Question for you, do you recommend I build a url with the variables TYPE, LA1,LO1 then pass the url with target as data being passed, is it possible to pass all the variables into the POST request?

Comment: I would need more details. Where is the curl command coming from? Because in that curl command TYPE, LA1 and LO1 are just strings part of the URL; they are not variables.

Comment: As a side note, it would be a good idea to also a fail callback by chaining .fail( function() { ... }) at the end of the ajax call.

Comment: TYPE, LA1 AND LO1 are all variables that the user inputs into the form, the structure of the cURL request is such that TYPE, LA1, LO1 will always have one value to each one, but the json {"target":[' LA2 ',' LO2 ']} could have multiple objects. hope that helped clarify my question!

Comment: And is the curl request functioning? Because from what i see in that command line, these variables are not passed in the POST data. However, if the API you are posting to is expecting them to be in the POST payload, then yes, you should add these to the data object. It all depends on what the end point (the server) is expecting.

Comment: i just reposted the code block to show you where I am at, it seems that I am not getting the solution doesn't work, even with the modification,

Comment: I don`t think you want data that the user types in to be part of the URL, unless it is in the query string, so I would not concatenate latitude_origin, and logitude origin to the URL, and probably not the mode either. However, I cannot tell you what the URL where you should post the data should be. That's for you to know. Same thing applies to the content of the JSON you are posting. I have no clue what the API on your server is expecting. Do you have any documentation about these? Or if you show me a cURL command that does what you want, that would help too.

Comment: I modified my answer above according to the additional details you gave me. However, I don't know the format of the JSON data the server is expecting, so I am only guessing for the data part.